# Suppress output in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is how I am plotting

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.figure();
pyplot.scatter(x=data[feat], y=data[target]);
pyplot.xlabel(feat);
pyplot.ylabel(target);
pyplot.show();
```

And I get output like

```
Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>

<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7fd80c2fbf50>

Text(0.5,0,'Age1')

Text(0,0.5,'Target')
```

How can I suppress this output? The semicolon did not work. I am running this in a jupyter notebook.

Comment: [Semicolons do suppress the output in jupyter/IPython.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXgIk.png) Where and how are you running this code?

Comment: jupyter notebook

Comment: The same is true of juypter notebook: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uacqT.png)

Comment: So why am I getting the output, is it a versioning issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign your calls to plot to a random variable name, and there won't be any output. By convention, this could be `_`, but you can use whatever variable name you want:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

_ = pyplot.figure()
_ = pyplot.scatter(x=data[feat], y=data[target])
_ = pyplot.xlabel('feat')
_ = pyplot.ylabel('target')
pyplot.show()
```

Note that unlike `MATLAB`, semi-colons don't suppress the output in `python`, they are simply used to delimit different statements, and are generally unnecessary if you are using newlines as delimiters (which is the standard way to do it)

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this though?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is documented here https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10794

You/Something has probably set your interactive shell to 

`from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"`

#### One solution is the change `all` to `last_expr`

The consequence of this is that a cell will display the output of the last expression rather than every expression. You could still of course `print` something and that would work normally.

#### Another solution is to add `;` to the last expression

for example, you could add 
`pass;`at the end of the cells, which would suppress output

#### A third option is as @sacul suggested, to assign outputs to variables by using some dummy variable.

Make sure you're not using that variable elsewhere